# How can I list mp3 files that have a leading period?

Tags: command-line, bash, ls

I have mp3 files in a directory. For this example, let's assume they are these 3:

```
Enter Sandman.mp3      ...And Justice For All.mp3      St. Anger.mp3
```

How can I list (**ls is highly preferred**) all mp3s?

As you can see, one song has leading periods, which is considered a hidden file.

The `-a` parameter in ls lets me view hidden files, but it does not help

`ls -a *.mp3` outputs:

```
Enter Sandman.mp3     St. Anger.mp3
```

And `ls -a .*.mp3` outputs only:

```
...And Justice for All.mp3
```

Please give me your thoughts on how I should list all mp3 files with or without leading periods.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could set the bash shell's `dotglob` parameter

```
shopt -s dotglob
```

Then the shell glob `*.mp3` will include files with leading periods

```
$ ls *.mp3
...And Justice For All.mp3  Enter Sandman.mp3  St. Anger.mp3
```

To restore the default behaviour, use `shopt -u dotglob`. Alternatively, using *extended globbing*

```
ls @(.|)*.mp3
```

will match mp3 files either starting or not starting with a period. Extended globbing should be enabled by default in interactive shells under Ubuntu, but if not you can do so with `shopt -s extglob`.

Comment: Thank you for the two options.
What do you recommend more since I am looking for the most portable option?

Comment: @user264974 I don't honestly know - I think I would choose the `@(.|)` extended glob if using it in an interactive shell, and the `shopt -s dotglob` if I needed something in a script - but I can't really justify why.